# How can I reference variable in different functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

[image]

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, address, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.phone = phone
    
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def set_address(self, address):
        self.address = address
    
    def set_phone(self, phone):
        self.phone = phone
    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_address(self):
        return self.address
    
    def get_phone(self):
        return self.phone
    
    
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, number, mail):
      self.number = number
      self.mailing_list = mail
    
    def set_number(self, number):
        self.number = number 
    
    def set_mailinglist(self, mail):
        self.mailing_list = mail
    
    def get_number(self):
        return self.number
    
    def get_mailinglist(self):
        if m == 'Y' or m == 'y':
            self.mailing_list = 'Yes'
        elif m =='N' or m =='n':
            self.mailing_list = 'No'
        return self.mailing_list
    

def main():
    me = Person(name= n , address = a, phone = p)
    
    n = input('Enter Customer Name: ')
    a = input('Enter Customer Address: ')
    p = input('Enter Customer Phone Number: ')
    
    print('Customer Name:', me.name)
    print('Customer Address:', me.address)
    print('Customer Phone Number:', me.phone)
    
    me1 = Customer(number= nu, mail = m)
    
    nu = int(input('Enter Customer Number: '))
    m = input('Add Customer to Mailing List [Y/N]?: ')
    
    print('Customer Number:', me1.number)
    print('Customer Mailing List:', me1.mailing_list)
    
main()
```

I want to make it where it'll print what the user answers in the input along with the other stuff. How am I able to get the variables I have in *main* to pass through the functions I have?
If there are any other mistakes I have made that I didn't notice, please let me know as I learn best on what was wrong and how to fix them.

Comment: Have you run your program? It'll throw an error at `me = Person(name= n , address = a, phone = p)`.

Comment: You can't use a variable before it's been defined. Accept input, store the user's responses in variables, then use those variables to initialize a Person rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the behavior seen is:

1. You have created an object of `Person` well before without taking the input.
2. Same for the obj of type `Customer`.

As you are creating object before taking the inputs, the values assigned to the member variables are `None`.
I have updated your function `main` by putting the code to create object of `Person` and `Customer` at right places and now it will work as expected.

```
def main():

    n = input('Enter Customer Name: ')
    a = input('Enter Customer Address: ')
    p = input('Enter Customer Phone Number: ')
    me = Person(name= n , address = a, phone = p)  # the right place to create obj

    print('Customer Name:', me.name)
    print('Customer Address:', me.address)
    print('Customer Phone Number:', me.phone)


    nu = int(input('Enter Customer Number: '))
    m = input('Add Customer to Mailing List [Y/N]?: ')
    me1 = Customer(number= nu, mail = m)    # right place to create object

    print('Customer Number:', me1.number)
    print('Customer Mailing List:', me1.mailing_list)
```